# WinEdt failing to consider multibib bibliographies outside the main tex file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, winedt, subdividing, multibib

I'm using `multibib` with WinEdt. If my main `.tex` file has:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{acks}{Acknowledgement page references}
```

then the `pdflatexify` process results in all the necessary output files. Also, when I press the <kbd>B</kbd> button, BibTeX gets called both for my main bibliography and for the acks bibliography. However, if I relegate these lines to a style file, outside the main `.tex` file, then WinEdt fails to create the relevant `.aux` file, and does not attempt to BibTeX the `.bib` file (which is in a subdirectory, by the way).

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: The following is my personal opinion: WinEdt is a commercial editor so such questions should be asked at the support site of WinEdt. http://www.winedt.com/support.html -- So I voted for closing "too localised".

Comment: I suspect we could do with a MWE here. I'm not sure what you mean by 'WinEdt fails to create ...' as this is done by pdfLaTeX, which is being run.

Comment: I've worked around this since asking the question and can't spare the time now to explore it, sorry... if you must, you can close it I suppose.